# Problem with imports when property of class has identical type as class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm newbie in Python so I would like to ask you for help. I have a class Test which has a property list of test, SubTests. Items in this list are same type as class. It looks like tree structure. Problem is that I'm getting an error when I start app and problem is with importing type Test.

"ImportError: cannot import name 'Test'"

I would like to keep setting type to the property and have a strong typing.

```py
from model.test import Test

class Test(object):
    Id = str
    SubTests = List[Test]
```

Comment: are you sure `Test` is in model.test?

Comment: 1) Did you put a `__init__.py` file with your `model` directory? 2) Is `model` directory in the same directory as the python file you are running?

Comment: What is `List`? And is `Test` a type annotation? In the end the import fails, so you need to make sure to have your resources in place.

Comment: you need parentheses to call `str()`

Comment: 1. Yes Test is in model.test (this is same file)

2. Nope I did not put init, yes model is a same directory where pasted file exists

3. list is from typing import List, I'm using Pycharm jetbrains if it helps

Comment: It looks like compiler doesn't see Test class inside Test class. When I've created other Test class above the current one

`class Test(object):
    pass`
I'm not receiving such an error